# How can I insert before a text without having any marker?

Tags: jquery, html

I have this html :

```
<th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-sat" data-date="2016-10-01">samedi 1 octobre</th>
```

And I want to insert something before `samedi 1 octobre` .

I already tried prepend() but it doesn't seems to work; the text disappears.

Have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add to the text that is already there

```
$('.fc-day-header.fc-widget-header.fc-sat').text(function(_,txt) {
    return 'Some text' + txt;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like `yourComponent.innerHtml = "your new text" + yourComponent.innerHtml;`